# Using next AUTO_INCREMENT id within query?

Tags: php, mysqli, auto-increment

I know that similar questions have been asked, but none of them seem to work for what I'm attempting.

I'm developing a system with mysqli/php that takes audio files, uploads them, renames them, and stores the name. The only problem is... I need the name of the file to be "uploadedfile_[$id_here].mp3"

I've got the entire upload system working properly, but I'm on the very last step... Getting the id to work.

The id column in this table is Auto_Increment. I just need to find out how to "predict" the Auto_Increment ID that will be given to this upcoming new row and tag it on the end of the audio file name by means of a variable.

One method I've attempted is:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'test_table'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$nextId = $row['Auto_increment'];

print $nextId;
```

But this doesn't return any results. My connections file should be configured properly as I've used it for other queries and it works fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't predict the next autoincrement id in a multi-user system. The solution is to do the insert with a stub record, get the id that is allocated for that to use in your filename, then update the stub as necessary

Comment: Expanding on Mark's comment - put the database part in a transaction, so it's very easy to cancel if you cannot persist the file for any reason.

Comment: So fetch the a_i value and then +1?

Comment: Nope. Start a transaction, insert a record, save the file using the a_i field. If everything's ok, commit, if something fails, rollback.

Comment: @Daniel - no.... consider user #1, gets an a_i value of 7, adds 1 to give 8; meanwhile user #2 also gets an a_i value of 7, adds 1 to give 8; user #1 writes to database with id 8; user #2 also tries to write to database with id 8..... you now have a corrupted database..... you never try to anticipate what the next a_i value will be, you always use the a_i value that is actually assigned by the database on creating a record

Comment: So can either of you post this as a detailed solution so I can test it? ;)

Comment: You can use auto_increment in mysql. However, You can find `max(id) + 1` to know the next available id or if you want to assign that in any column, use `id=id+1` instead.

Comment: I don’t see the problem here – why don’t you just create the record, and rename the uploaded file afterwards …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on how frequent this code will run, surely?

Auto-incrementation works by increasing by 1 each time. a record is inserted, I've just started PHP myself but surely you could just add 1 to your...

```
 $nextId = $row['Auto_increment'];
```

which would give you the next ID coming up. Unless, as Maerlyn stated, you have two users at the same time, in which case I think you could insert into a temp table whilst the record is being inserted, and if it succeeds, inset into the main table and remove from the temp table. When inserting into the temp table you'd first have to run a check to see if the record already exists in the temp table before attempting anything.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Got it running, added 1 to the value and now it is working perfectly to add the id to the end. Because this is for the backend of a website which typically only one person uses, it shouldn't be a problem with duplicates. Thanks everyone!

Comment: IF you feel I answered your question, you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just execute your INSERT query and then get  `$mysqli->insert_id`

http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.insert-id.php